# Concatenating fields of a feature class using python without field calculator

Tags: python, field, concatenation, arcgis, string-concatenation

This seems like it should be relatively straightforward, but I have not been able to get it to work.

I have a feature class within which I would like to concatenate attributes. I would like to combine a county identification field (county FIPS code) with a unique identifier field that I generated.  I would like to be able to do this within my Python script, and NOT within field calculator, however, I have gotten error messages for everything I have attempted.  Both fields are currently stored as strings.  Does anyone have any advice on how I might go about this?

This is what I would like the result to be, with the 'unique_id' and 'id_num' fields combining to make the 'final_id' field:
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4k30.png) I did this in the field calculator and would like to automate this in my python script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I'm understanding your question correctly here:

In python, it should come out looking something like this:

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management(TableX, "final_id", "!unique_id! +  !id_num! ", "PYTHON_9.3", "")
```

As a general rule, a good method for getting 'vetted' python code for a given operation, is to re-create the particular process using Model Builder, then just go ***Model > Export > To Python Script*** .